# logging into a LXC container

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, lxc

Trying to create LXC container to run 32bit Wine on my 64bit machine. I have done all as instructed. Then coming to the part, where to start the container:

```
sudo lxc-start -n my32bitbox
```

After a while of starting, it prompts for user name and password. In the install instructions it says that own user name and password can be used, but I get incorrect login. Also same error when trying in with default login, username: `ubuntu` password: `ubuntu`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which instructions were you following?

Comment: http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOn64bit

Comment: Have you resolved this problem> For me it say log inincorect even if is a empty password